# How to apply centrifugal force in box2d?

Tags: box2d

I attached a dynamic body to a static body using a rope joint in box2d testbed. I want the dynamic body to spin around the static body when 'a' or 'd' is pressed. I don't want to use a revolute joint because the length of a revolute joint is fixed. So I want to apply centrifugal force on the object, can someone tell me how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you just mean a regular 'force'... which you could do with ApplyForce. Is there something special that makes it 'centrifugal'?

Comment: @iforce2d actually there is nothing too special, it's just that I don't know how to apply a force to make a object spin another object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with testbed but the logic behind what you're asking is fairly simple. What you want to do is find the angle between the dynamic body and the static body. With that angle you simply create a new `Vector2(x,y)` which will represent your force to use with the ApplyForce.

In java it would look like:

```
    // This is the dimension of the vector representing the applied force (you choose that)
    float forceDimension = 10;

    // This is the angle you have to find (I use PI since the Math class uses radians)
    // PI radians == 90 degrees (your dynamic body would then be directly above your static body)
    double angle = Math.PI;

    // This is the actual vector of the force
    Vector2 force = new Vector2(forceDimension * (float) Math.sin(angle), forceDimension * (float) Math.cos(angle));
```

Then you can re-calculate this force every update and apply it to the dynamic body.